# chrome shortcut or extension to hide tabs/bar/bookmarks

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Sometimes i resize one browser window and move it to the corner of the screen to play video, i set it on top of other windows using [DeskPins](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/deskpins.html) (Which fortunately still works in Windows 7)

So what i want is a shortcut that hide the tab bar, address bar and bookmarks bar all at once, so i can set the window to the smaller size possible. Sort of like F11 but without going full screen.

Also, if i hit Ctrl-Shift-B to hide the bookmark bar it hide on all windows.

Anyone know of a way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do that in Chrome. However, if you're willing to switch to Firefox you can disable all of the toolbars (and tab bar) and have it look like this:

[image: Firefox w/o toolbars]